# How to write chemical equation in HTML?

Tags: html, css

How to write the below ion in HTML?
[image]

I already tried the below code but it doesn't look good

```html
<p> [% chlorine in liquid bleach] − 1 = Total parts of water for each part of bleach  <sub></sub> </p> <br>
<p> [% chlorine desired]</p>
```

Comment: It is harder as you would think, but possible. Typically, some lib is used for that, for example MathML or more likely Math.js or Latex.js . All of these libs are big.

Comment: If you need only this formula you could master it visually only by HTML/CSS, but if you need to place many formulas on your site, then use a library.

Comment: @Azu could you help me how to write the following equation given in image?

Comment: Sure. Only one question: `-1` should be at the level of the line?

Comment: @Azu yes IN front of line

Comment: Another solution is to use an image. As the question is closed I cannot add an answer here.

Comment: @Azu if you could share the code here in comment?

Comment: .container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .container .fraction div:first-child {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .container .fraction div:nth-child(2) {
        text-align: center;
    }      
    .container .second {
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

Comment: <div class="container">
        <div class="fraction">
            <div>
                [% chlorine in liquid bleach]
            </div>
            <div>
                [% chlorine desired]
            </div>           
        </div>
        <div class="second">
            − 1 = Total parts of water for each part of bleach
        </div>
    </div>